# D7 - Get Path Alias (URL) from referenced Taxonomy Value

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm trying to avoid using the PHP filter due to security concerns.

I have a CCK type I already created called **Slide** that I am dumping out in a view. The Block dumps out all of the items with content type **Slide** which are then used in a homepage slider.

Within the CCK type, I have an Entity Reference field called *Prog Reference* that references a taxonomy value.

What I need is the URL that is associated with that Taxonomy value so I can link up the actual slide.

They click the slide -- takes them to that taxonomy term page.

Current setup:

**Referenced entity**: Prog Reference -- http://d.pr/i/10bX

```
 Entity Reference: Prog Reference
```

**Fields**: d.pr/i/oa3z *(wouldn't let me post as link)*

```
(Taxonomy term entity referenced from field_prog_reference) Taxonomy term: Term ID
Content: Slider Image
```

No **Taxonomy term: Path** :( -- d.pr/i/FtcC *(wouldn't let me post as link)*

```
Taxonomy term: Name
  The taxonomy term name.
Taxonomy term: Programming Image
  Appears in: taxonomy_term:programming_type.
Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term
  The Taxonomy term of the current relationship rendered using a view mode.
Taxonomy term: Term description
  The description associated with a taxonomy term.
Taxonomy term: Term edit link
  Provide a simple link to edit the term.
Taxonomy term: Term ID
  The tid of a taxonomy term.
Taxonomy term: Weight
  The term weight field
```

Typically you would just use the *Content: Path* field to get the referenced entity's path, but for some reason this isn't an option Taxonomy values?

**Any ideas? All help welcome!! Appreciate in advance!**

Comment: Drupal 7, right? Do you need this as a field on a content type or within a view result?

Comment: Oh, are you limiting the number of taxonomy terms referenced to 1?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll edit to add in D7. It's within a view result. Essentially I'm rewriting the slide image output to include a link to the referenced taxonomy value. Taxonomy terms are also limited to 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then, here are a two options.

Option 1)

- Include your entity reference field.
- Use the 'Label' formatter.
- Rewrite it's output and to /taxonomy/term/[field_entity_reference-target_id], see screenshot.

[image]

This will output the path to the term page as plain text for you to use as you will. You could output this field as a link and attempt the same pattern.

Option 2)
+ Add a relationship to the referenced entity. See screenshots.
[image]

[image]

- Once you add the relationship, add the Taxonomy term: Name field using the relationship. See screenshot.

[image]

<> Then configure to use link and rewrite output if desired.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I knew about option 1 and 2, but neither suffice at this point. Option 1 will allow me to put in the link *but* I won't have the alias. Which is bad for SEO. Option 2 would require a "Read More" link under the slides and the user wouldn't be able to click the slide to take them to the page.

Comment: I ended up just adding a field in the CCK type for the URL and having to hard-code it in. I honestly don't think Drupal supports the alias unless you write a module OR use the PHP field module (which is a huge security no-no).